# Hidden Variables in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

I need to get the hidden variable's value definied in my Facelets file to process a transaction in my bean. I used the below line in the process action method to get the hidden input component. But I am getting `null`. How can I get the specified hidden input value?

The bean:

```
UIInput classNameComponent = (UIInput) event.getComponent().findComponent("className");
```

The view:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/content.xhtml">
...
    <h:form id="classForm">
    ...
        <o:dataTable id="classTable">
        ...
            <f:facet name="import">
                    <h:inputHidden id="className" value="com.LoadClass" />
            </f:facet>
            ...
        </o:dataTable>
    ...
    </h:form>
...
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Even though you found the answer yourself, there are nicer ways to achieve this. I only first need to know if you're using JSF 1.x or 2.x (and you should mention that in the future JSF questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer!!! I have got it by the below mentioned approach..

```
className = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .getRequestParameterMap().get("classForm:className");
```